# Sql query causes python to crash

Tags: python, sqlite

The following query causes python to crash ('python.exe has encountered a problem ...' 
Process terminated with an exit code of -1073741819

The query is:

```
create temp table if not exists MM_lookup2 as 
select lower(Album) || lower(SongTitle) as concat, ID    
from MM.songs    
where artist like '%;%' collate nocase
```

If I change from "like" to = it runs as expected, eg

```
create temp table if not exists MM_lookup2 as 
select lower(Album) || lower(SongTitle) as concat, ID    
from MM.songs    
where artist = '%;%' collate nocase
```

I am running python v2.7.2, with whatever version of sqlite that ships in there.

The problem query runs without problem outside python.

Comment: UPDATE: I had a another look to see if anything is "strange" about this situation. The only things I could think of were that the database is encoded to UTF-16le, and that the database being queried was an attached one, not the one first connected to. ... I changed the program to remove the 2nd issue (ie. directly connected the MM database) ... this didn't correct the problem.

Comment: UPDATE 2: The problem seems isolated to just one db, the one created by MediaMonkey. They have implemented an in-house versionof "like" function [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/MediaMonkey_Database_structure) ... "This MM-specific implementation of LIKE, automatically uses the @-sign as the escape character and it is always applied. It means that you need to modify the SearchString to correctly use this function." ... Don't know if this is what causes my problem, but it seems likely I suppose. I can't find how to get the @ escape character past sqlite. .. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can your share you python code where this query has been implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write the database system/driver you are using. I suspect that your SQL is the problem. The % characters needs to be escaped. Possibly the db driver module tries to interpret %, and %) as format chars, and it cannot convert non-existing parameter value into a format that is acceptable by the database backend.

Can you please give us concrete Python code? Can you please try to run the same query but putting the value of '%,%' into a parameter, and pass it to the cursor as a parameter?